# In 1 query: 2 results, using 2 conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with columns type(0 or 1), amount(int)

I need query what returns 2 params: sum amount for type = 1 and sum amount for type = 0

2 queries:

`SELECT SUM(amount) AS income FROM table WHERE type = 0;`

`SELECT SUM(amount) AS expense FROM table WHERE type = 1;`

But can i return these params using only 1 query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT sum(case when type = 0 
           then amount
           else 0 
           end) AS income,
       sum(case when type = 1 
           then amount
           else 0
           end) AS expense
FROM table
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7b0d/7)

Comment: @FahimParkar: Thank you for adding a SQLFiddle demo. But normally this would be a comment since other peoples answers should only be **corrected** and not **enhanced**.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT SUM(amount), IF(type=0, 'income', 'expense') AS type
FROM table
GROUP BY type
```

Comment: hhm, it's returns 2 columns `SUM(amount)= 700` and `type = income`

Comment: but i need `income = xxx` and `expense = xxx`